# Loading CSS chunk 8812 failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-analytics

I am trying to open AWS IOT Core and getting below error. I had tried with Google Chome and Microsoft Edge but similar error in both web browser.

> Error: Loading CSS chunk 8812 failed.
> (https://iotcore.us-east-2.prod.console.iot.aws.dev/static/css/8812.chunk.css)
> at o.onerror.o.onload (https://iotcore.us-east-2.prod.console.iot.aws.dev/static/js/iotcore.js?time=1690995483138:2:380015)